# Python Bokeh embedded hplot

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to embed multiple bokeh charts in a website with an horizontal layout. Following the example code from the Bokeh user guide:

```
from bokeh.io import hplot, output_file, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file("layout.html")

x = list(range(11))
y0 = x
y1 = [10 - i for i in x]
y2 = [abs(i - 5) for i in x]

# create a new plot
s1 = figure(width=250, plot_height=250, title=None)
s1.circle(x, y0, size=10, color="navy", alpha=0.5)

# create another one
s2 = figure(width=250, height=250, title=None)
s2.triangle(x, y1, size=10, color="firebrick", alpha=0.5)

# create and another
s3 = figure(width=250, height=250, title=None)
s3.square(x, y2, size=10, color="olive", alpha=0.5)

# put all the plots in an HBox
p = hplot(s1, s2, s3)

# show the results
show(p)
```

It works fine, however since I need to embed the plots in a webpage, I replace the last line with:

```
from bokeh.embed import components
script, div = components(p)
html = "%s\n%s"%(script,div)
```

So that I can add the html to the main page (together with Bokeh CDN). However in this case the plots are organized vertically and I can't seem to figure out if there is a solution to this problem.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Edit1:**I seem to have understood the problem, passing the hplot object to the components function only creates one div that somehow does not display the plots inline. One option is to pass the list of plots to the component and add CSS to make those divs inline. Still I think there must be a easier way that I am missing.